# Difference between Current Directory and Working Directory in Windows

Tags: windows, working-directory

What is the difference between Current Directory and Working Directory in Windows? How can one change working Directory for applications like Notepad++ or Mozilla Firefox?

Answer (score 7):

Current directory and working directory are just two different names for the same thing. Each process maintains a single current directory.

The current directory is specified on startup as a parameter to whichever function is used to create the process, for example `CreateProcess`. How do you change the current directory for one of your applications? Well, it depends how you start it.

- If you start it from a shortcut, change the properties of the shortcut to specify the current directory.
- If you start from a command prompt, the current directory will be the current directory of the command prompt at the moment that you start it.
- If you start by calling `CreateProcess`, the working current will be whatever you pass to  `CreateProcess` in the `lpCurrentDirectory` parameter. If you pass `NULL` then the current directory of the parent process will be used.

Comment: When I start Notepad++ from shortcut I see the current Directory in Process Explorer. I see it as C:\Windows.  When I do a createProcess and set some valid Directory(say D:\abcd) in lpCurrentDirectory field, it is still showing C:\Windows. Shouldn't it show D:\abcd?

Comment: Well, remember that a process can modify its own current directory any time it likes. Perhaps npp is doing that. I don't know. It's also possible that there's a flaw in your `CreateProcess` call.

Comment: Thanks :)... I'm sorry I'm unable to upvote your answer because I'm new to Stackoverflow and my reputation is below 15 points. I will do it once I get them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Re "*If you start it from a shortcut, change the properties of the shortcut to specify the current directory*"; But how do you do that?

Comment: @Pacerier Right click on the shortcut, select properties, and edit the Start in field.