# Cannot run a .exe file from windows form - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, gcc, exe

I have build a simple windows form where when i press a button run a process indicated in a TextBox

I have tried with this code

```
Try
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(TextBox1.Text)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error")
End Try
```

Code works, but I don't understand why I canno't run a .exe genereted from a compiled c project using gcc (which is my goal).

I have tried to execute as Administrator too.

Someone can explain me?

Comment: Can you run the target GCC-generated program from a `cmd.exe` window? It probably has dependencies on other files in the same folder. Try using `ShellExecute` or setting the `ProcessStartInfo`'s working-directory.

Comment: Yes, I can run the GCC-generated program from a cmd; and yes the target program has dependencies on a txt files in the same folder.

I have search for _ShellExecute_ and _ProcessStartInfo_ for visual basic but I'm having some problem.

Can you share me an example code?

Comment: It's `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute`.

Comment: It works! I have forgotten to create an 
instance for ProcessStartInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Converting my comment to an answer)

> Code works, but I don't understand why I canno't run a .exe genereted from a compiled c project using gcc (which is my goal).

I suspect the problem is that your `gcc`-compiled executable has runtime dependencies on files located in the same filesystem directory as your `gcc`-compiled executable and it references those files only by their short-names (e.g. "someFile.txt") instead of by their absolute-path filenames (e.g. `"C:\my-gcc-program\bin\someFile.txt"`) then the OS looks inside that process' Working Directory ([aka Current Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334097/difference-between-current-directory-and-working-directory-in-windows)).

Note that when your program uses `Process.Start(String fileName)` then the newly created (child) OS process inherits your process's Working Directory rather than it being reset to the new process' executable's filename's parent directory!

So if your child process expects "someFile.txt" to be in its working-directory then you need to launch the child-process with the correct working-directory instead of it inheriting it from your process.

You can do this in 2 different ways, both of which require you to use `ProcessStartInfo` instead of any of the `Process.Start` overloads that accept `String fileName`.

#### Option 1: Set `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory` directly:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = @"C:\my-gcc-program\bin\program.exe",
    WorkingDirectory = @"C:\my-gcc-program\bin",
}

using( Process p = Process.Start( psi ) )
{
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

#### Option 2: Use `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute`;

The `UseShellExecute` option creates the new process as though the user started it through their OS shell, such as `cmd.exe` or `Explorer.exe` rather than as a child process of your process. (One of the many) effects of this option is that the OS handles setting the Working-directory of this new process automatically for you.

Note that in .NET Framework, this is `true` by default - but `false` in .NET Core (and will cause errors if used in UWP). Because it's not `true` by default in .NET Core you should set it explicitly if you're depending on it to work on all platforms besides UWP.

Note that when using `UseShellExecute == true`, you still must provide a valid `WorkingDirectory` path, [however its purposes changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=netcore-3.1):

> - The `WorkingDirectory` property behaves differently when `UseShellExecute is true` than when `UseShellExecute is false`.
>
>   - When `UseShellExecute` is true, the `WorkingDirectory` property specifies the location of the executable.
>
>     - If `WorkingDirectory` is an empty string, the current directory is understood to contain the executable.
>     - When `UseShellExecute is true`, the working directory of the application that starts the executable is also the working directory of the executable.
>   - When `UseShellExecute is false`, the `WorkingDirectory` property is not used to find the executable. Instead, its value applies to the process that is started and only has meaning within the context of the new process.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = @"program.exe",
    WorkingDirectory = @"C:\my-gcc-program\bin",
    UseShellExecute = true
}

using( Process p = Process.Start( psi ) )
{
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dai
I post here the code who I have written in Button click event. Maybe can be useful for someone

`
Try
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = True 'normaly true
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\workDirectory"
    startInfo.FileName = TextBox1.Text
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error")
End Try
`

Answer (score 0):

I post here the code who I have written in Button click event. Maybe can be useful for someone

```
Try
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\workDirectory"
    startInfo.FileName = TextBox1.Text
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error")
End Try
```

Thanks @Dai for help